# The problem of receiving many requests in geoplugin.net

Tags: php

why after I upload my website I keep getting the following error when I try to call a function that uses Geoplugin? even though it works fine on the local server.

I googled and found possible answers: allow_url_fopen must be turned on in php configuration. I contacted my hosting support but they said nothing is wrong from their end.

Please, what should I do to solve this problem??

HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests

Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=154.160.16.108): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests in /home/xxxxx/joker.com/xxxx/xxx/myfunc.php on line 578

MY PHP FUNCTION :

```
<?php
$uid = $_GET['userid'];
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
{
    $real_ip_adress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
{
    $real_ip_adress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
else
{
    $real_ip_adress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

$cip = $real_ip_adress;
$iptolocation = 'http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=' . $cip;
$creatorlocation = file_get_contents($iptolocation);
$json = file_get_contents($iptolocation);
$data = json_decode($json);
$country = $data->geoplugin_countryName;
?>
```

Comment: Too Many Requests means the remote server thinks you made too many requests from that address in a short time. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429. Presumably they put limits on to prevent excessive consumption of their resources. Maybe you can ask them if they have a way to allow you to make more requests, e.g. by paying a subscription or something.

Comment: Actually I had a quick look and I think I'm right. https://www.geoplugin.com/premium says _"geoPlugin is free within the limit of 120 lookups per minute.

If you wish to remove these limits, you may subscribe to the premium geolocation web service"_ and then goes on to describe how much they charge for usage over and above the limit. https://www.geoplugin.com/aup is also relevant to your situation - it says _"Greater than 120 API requests per minute will get you blacklisted for 1 hour, during which time you will receive a "429 Too Many Requests" response."_.

Comment: You could also have read https://www.geoplugin.com/faq to find this out, too. If you don't think you have this many visitors to your page per minute, then read further down that page to find out reasons why it might still happen.

Comment: I actually have this many requests per minute, but I can't subscribe at this price on the site
Is there another free website that has no limits like
https://ip-api.com/

Comment: Can you modify my code on this other site?
 ip-api.com